# Are formulas supported on fields in Office Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Scenario I'd like to use:

I want to have two fields in a Word document. I would like to enter a date in the first one. Then I want the second one to display a value based on the date I entered in the first field.

Is there support for this kind of scenario in Office Word 2007?

I looks on the web but couldn't find any useful info. I did find info about formula support but not for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert a spreadsheet inside your Word document to realize your scenario (`Insert > Table > Excel Spreadsheet`). Without the use of Excel, you can't use date formulas in MS Word. Anyway, you can use tables in order to be able to make use of some functions in MS Word. To do that, insert a new table, click inside a cell, go to `Table Tools > Layout > Data` box, and click `Formula`. A formula window opens and you can enter a formula by selecting a function from the list. In this list, there are only basic functions like `sum`, `min`, `max`, `and`, `or`, `not`, etc. You can actually type a date in a cell, and set another cell equal to that one, but the formula result cannot be displayed properly as you are just allowed to select one of the Number Formats which don't include any Date Formats. For more info on how to perform calculations in a table in MS Word, see [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP052567361033.aspx).

I hope this helps.